# Get latest added database objects

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I want to fetch the tables and stored procedures added in last 5 or 6 months to a particular database.

I have tried using the below command but it is not giving correct data.

```
select * from sys.objects
where type = 'U' or type = 'P'
and modify_date between '2012-09-01' and '2013-01-29'
```

Please suggest which command can give me this list.

Comment: How do you know it's not correct? Can you show an example of data that is wrong?

Comment: Because the tables it is listing are present in that database much before.I want the latest added tables and SPs.

Comment: So did you mean to use `create_date`?

Comment: I am aware of create date.. parenthesis was the trick..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for objects ADDED, then why are you querying on modify_date? Shouldn't you be looking at create_date?

```
select * from sys.objects
where (type = 'U' or type = 'P')
and create_date between '2012-09-01' and '2013-01-29'
```

Also, you have not put your `OR` in parentheses, which means that you will get incorrect results anyway.
Raj